# Android : import libraries Like PhotoView

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-library

I'm a beginner in android programming

And I have problem importing this library to eclipse: [External Link To Project (GitHub)](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView)

I know how to import .jar files but I can't find any .jar file in it's libraries

The question is:

How can I use [this](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) type of libraries (with only .java files)?

Comment: If the project is of type "library": Build the project. It creates a jar. Then import that jar as usual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pull that library project from git repo and follow [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject) link on developer's site.

Answer (score 0):

(I understand it's a very old question, but I thought adding this would be beneficial and somebody might find it useful.)

If you are using Android Studio, you can directly add Maven dependencies in you build.gradle file. This can save a lots of time and hassle.

e.g. link for OP's original request
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.chrisbanes.photoview/library/1.2.3

Answer (score 0):

For whosoever that may still encounter this challenge just paste the following in your gradle app:
implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes.photoview:library:1.2.1'
and sync to import the library into your project.