# Importing PhotoView?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, imageview, project

Ok so I want to chisbanes PhotoView.. I'm pulling my hair out now, Been staring at the screen for over an hour and for the life of me, I cannot figure out how to get this to even import into eclipse.

I've downloaded the git so I have my PhotoView-master folder with plenty of things in there (Looks like a project tbh). But no jar?

I came across this question which was marked as answered but I simply could not figure this one out.

[Android : import libraries Like PhotoView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21110640/android-import-libraries-like-photoview)

I went through this

http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject

But once again, there's nothing even available for me to add.

Anyone know what I need to do to actually get this loaded into eclipse and ready to reference?

Cheers in advance

Answer (score 2):

Ok so I managed to get it working after hours slaving away at the screen.

First you need to move everything under the java/uk folder to the src/ folder in Eclipse. Once you do it the src/uk/... should look as normal. Next you need to go the project properties, click on Android and then change the Target Build Path to match the project you will be importing the library into.

Then just follow the instructions on the android dev webpage and then you should be able to reference the required files.

Answer (score 0):

Working with library is a pain in android. 
Photo view is not a jar library it is a referenced library. so you have to download the zip and import it inot ecllipse. Also if the library is built using Android Studio then you have to change folders to make it work. For eg the source code in Android Studio is in java folder while in ecllipse it is in src.

Comment: Looks like it's an android studio project then as there is a java folder with the source at the very bottom of that structure. Would that explain why the .java files have a different looking icon?

Comment: it doesnot need any explanation please ask ecllipse devlopers for that lol.